# Applying LabelEncoder in Sklearn across multiple columns that have both text and numbers

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to apply Sklearn (0.24.1) Labelencoder to a data set where some the columns have text and numbers mixed together.

```
dataset.csv
filename1, cat, dog, elephant, hamster, 1, 7, 8, 4, 10
filename2, hamster, dog, lizard, 7, 5, 3, 8, 19, 1
filename3, raccoon, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 3, 23
filename4, turtle, cat, lizard, bird, fish, 6, 2, 4, 11
filename5, bird, donkey, 5, 2, 8, 2, 6, 7, 3
```

I'm trying to turn all the animal names into numerical values.  Below is the code that I'm trying to use.

```
input_file = "dataset.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0)
numDF = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df)
```

But when I run this I get the error:

```
TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this [detailed example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html) about `ColumnTransformer`.

In short, you would use something like:

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('categorical', OneHotEncoder(), ['filename', 'animal'])],
    remainder='passthrough',
)
numerical_df = preprocessor.fit_transform(df)
```

However, that would only work if you have fixed columns titled "filename" and "animal" in your dataframe. It seems that you have a variable number of columns with animals in each row, which will require some custom preprocessing, not well suited for scikit-learn.